# Create private dblink from another user

Tags: oracle, dblink

I have the following situation:

- `ADMIN_USER` - privileged user that can execute whatever he wants and also we use it to deploy scripts to different envs
- `REGULAR_USER` - just a regular schema that holds executable code

I want to create private dblink for `REGULAR_USER` under `ADMIN_USER` (while deploying my scripts).

Questions:

1. Can I achieve this?
2. If so then what privileges should I give to `REGULAR_USER`/what actions should I do?

Oracle version is 11gR2

Comment: Why do you want to create a link?  Exaclty how do you envision using it?  This has all the earmarks of an 'x-y question' and I suspect you are asking the wrong question https://xyproblem.info/   Put it another way, what is the _business_ problem you are trying to solve? (BTW, 11g has been out of support for about 2 years now.  12c has also recently gone out of support.  Long past time to upgrade).

Comment: I want `REGULAR_USER` to use it but I don't want to share it with anyone else (e.g. create it as `PUBLIC`). I could create it under `REGULAR_USER` but our CI/CD process uses privileged schema to deploy scripts under it so that's why I have to do it exactly this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Privileged users can *indirectly* create database links for other users. The privileged user must temporarily grant the regular user `CREATE DATABASE LINK`, create a temporary procedure in the regular user's schema that will create the database link,  execute that procedure, and then drop the temporary procedure and privilege.

```
create user regular_user identified by regular_user;
grant create session to regular_user;

grant create database link to regular_user;

create or replace procedure regular_user.create_db_link is
begin
    execute immediate
    q'[
        create database link test_link
        connect to regular_user
        identified by "regular_user"
        using 'orcl'
     ]';
end;
/

begin
    regular_user.create_db_link;
end;
/

drop procedure regular_user.create_db_link;

revoke create database link from regular_user;
```

Comment: Such an awesome use of `authid definer` clause! Great thanks, that's what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question: No, you cannot achieve this.

Private database links *must* be created by the owner of the link. You cannot create a private link in another schema, and you cannot use (directly) a private link in another schema, even as the SYS user. You can use a private link *indirectly* if there is - for instance - also a view in the other schema which references the link.

So in your case, `REGULAR_USER` would have to have the `CREATE DATABASE LINK` privilege, and would have to execute the DDL for the link - `ADMIN_USER` cannot do it. If `ADMIN_USER` wanted to use that link, then `REGULAR_USER` would also have to create a view to reference something on the other end of the link and make the view selectable for `ADMIN_USER`.